# WPForm, how to set date to tomorrow

Tags: forms, date

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.wpforms_datepicker = {
        disableMobile: true,
        // Don't allow users to pick past dates
        minDate: new Date(),
    }
</script>
<?php
```

so I am using this code to now allow users to pick past dates, is it possible to make it so they are only allowed to choose date starting tomorrow from current date.

Also is it possible to control the timepicker as well?, if I want date and time to only be available starting 24 hours from current date and time.